# IntelliJ IDEA 13.0 constant debug mode for app?

Tags: java, android, debugging, intellij-idea

I have developed an app in IntelliJ IDEA 13.0 however when I run the app on my device it constantly waits for the debugger (if I run in debug mode it's fine as the debugger connects) however if away from the computer I cannot run the app as the following message appears.

```
Waiting For Debugger
Application XXXXXX
(process uk.co.xxxxx.xxxxx) is waiting for the debugger to attach
Force Close
```

This works when at the computer:

[image]

This never works either at the computer or when away from:

[image]

Does anyone know why this may be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also noticed this and it appears to have been a bug in IntelliJ Idea 13.0, 13.1.x seems to have resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

Make a release (non-debug) version of the application and install it on device.

If you use Gradle

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

if you use Ant

```
ant release
```

You will have to generate a signing key and [sign your application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

If you use Gradle you can make use of this [build script](https://gist.github.com/grzegorz-zur/6416924) to sign your application.

Your newly generated application will have different signing key that the old one as it used debug signing key. First remove the old one from your device.
Then install release APK file using this commands:

```
adb install APPLICATINO.apk
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought that the play button ran it without attaching the debugger, other apps are fine it is just this one so I am assuming there is a setting somewhere that is different?